# Pass variables between separate instances of ruby (without writing to a text file or database)

Tags: ruby, global-variables, ipc

Lets say I'm running a long worker-script in one of several open interactive rails consoles.

The script is updating columns in a very, very, very large table of records. I've muted the ActiveRecord logger to speed up the process, and instruct the script to output some record of progress so I know how roughly how long the process is going to take. That is what I am currently doing and it would look something like this:

```
ModelName.all.each_with_index do |r, i|
  puts i if i % 250
  ...runs some process...
  r.save
end
```

Sometimes its two nested arrays running, such that there would be multiple iterators and other things running all at once.

Is there a way that I could do something like this and access that variable from a separate rails console? (such that the variable would be overwritten every time the process is run without much slowdown)

```
records = ModelName.all
$total = records.count
records.each_with_index do |r, i|
  $i = i
  ...runs some process...
  r.save
end
```

*meanwhile mid-process in other console*

```
puts "#{($i/$total * 100).round(2)}% complete"
#=> 67.43% complete
```

I know passing global variables from one separate instance of ruby to the next doesn't work. I also just tried this to no effect as well

*unix console 1*

```
 $X=5
 echo {$X}
 #=> 5
```

*unix console 2*

```
echo {$X}
#=> ""
```

Lastly, I also know using global variables like this is a major software design pattern no-no. I think that's reasonable, but I'd still like to know how to break that rule if I'd like.

Writing to a text file obviously would work. So would writing to a separate database table or something. That's not a bad idea. But the really cool trick would be sharing a variable between two instances without writing to a text file or database column.

What would this be called anyway? Tunneling? I don't quite know how to tag this question. Maybe bad-idea is one of them. But honestly design-patterns isn't what this question is about.

## Some solutions I worked out using the answers:

Here's a quick implementation I set up that appears to be working:

The system typically requires three separate classes (in my case, I use classes for all because I'm in rails and its easier)

the counter class: this is passed into DRb and then all its methods can be accessed via the client. Thus, this object can be extremely complex.

```
class Counter
  attr_accessor :i
  def initialize
    @i = 0
  end
  def report(total)
    "#{(@i.to_f / total.to_f * 100).round(2)}%"
  end
end
```

The counter server. Counter is passed into this one. In my case the process hangs and thus does not return anything and cannot be accessed. I haven't figured out how to run it as a daemon accessible via object so its best to pass in the uri and control that so nothing needs to be returned. Whats nice about this is you can just let it run for a very long time and rewrite the variables accessible via the accessor methods called via attr_accessor. Ruby makes it super easy.

```
require 'drb'
class CounterServer
  def initialize(uri="druby://:9000")
    DRb.start_service(uri, Counter.new)
    puts "server running on #{DRb.uri}"
    trap("INT") {DRb.stop_service}
    DRb.thread.join
  end
end
```

the client. allows you to access the server.

```
require 'drb'
class CounterClient
  attr_reader :client, :total
  def initialize(uri="druby://:9000", records)
    @client = DRbObject.new nil, uri
    @total = records.count
  end
  def incremement
    @client.i += 1
  end
  def monitor_and_report
    values = []
    puts "you must first set the @total value! This should be done in the ruby script being monitored by passing in the records as a first variable for initialize" if @client.total.nil?
    5/0 if @client.total.nil?
    while ((@client.i) < (@client.total))
      values << pctg_complete
      puts "#{pctg_complete}%"
      last_index = (values.count - 1)
      percentage_per_second = get_slope(values[last_index], values[last_index - 1])
      puts get_eta(percentage_per_second, values[last_index]) unless values.count == 1
      sleep 10
    end
  end

  def get_slope(latest, second_latest)
    run  = 10.0# seconds
    rise = (latest - second_latest)
    slope = (rise/run)
    slope
  end

  def get_eta(velocity, current)
    puts "velocity: #{velocity}"
    puts "current: #{current}"
    pctg_left_to_complete = (100.0 - current)
    puts "pctg_left: #{pctg_left_to_complete}"
    estimated_seconds_remaining = pctg_left_to_complete / velocity
    minutes_left = (estimated_seconds_remaining / 60.0).round(0)
    "estimated #{minutes_left} minutes until completion"
  end
```

So, in the example of my question:

*console 1*

```
CounterServer.new
#=> hangs while server runs
```

*console (ruby script) 2*

```
records = ModelName.all
c = CounterClient.new(nil, records)
records.each_with_index do |r, i|
  c.increment
  ...runs code...
  r.save
 end
```

*console 3*

```
c = CounterClient.new
c.monitor_and_report
```

**Note several weeks later looking at this again:**
This code could be much simpler. For one, the Counter class doesn't need to be reporting anything. All it needs is the attr_accessor method. The server & client could be stripped down to only just a few lines as well.

*However*, the script here has a bit more of a thematic element to it. I have yet to use it once since I wrote it but learning how to communicate between separate ruby consoles seems to me to be a very powerful skill.

**UPDATE**
The "smaller functions" of this watch **no not** work. Namely the eta function. It's a piece of ****

Comment: This is called interprocess-communication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Drb. It works by creating a distributed ruby service(server), a client then connects to it and is able to fetch Ruby objects from it.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/drb/rdoc/DRb.html

Comment: This is the quick solution I think. I also found a tutorial for a counter much like the one I described in my example here: http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/drb.htm

Comment: I simply cannot believe how simple the tutorial at that link is given the complexity of this subject

Comment: Well, it's Ruby ;) Also there are two books on this topic only 
http://www.amazon.com/Distributed-Programming-Ruby-Mark-Bates/dp/0321638360

http://www.amazon.com/The-dRuby-Book-Distributed-Computing/dp/193435693X

Answer (score 0):

Have ruby emit the data on a unix channel, like STDERR or STDOUT. Then pipe that output to the other ruby-based receiver.

That secondary process will do nothing but idle and the check its STDIN for data – finding any, it will printed to the screen.

You could also have the long-running script do this by emitting the data [when it traps a given signal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Signal.html). Thus, the logging operation happens only as frequently as you signal it.

```
memcached_client = get_memcashed_singleton

begin
  if record_count % 250 == 0
    Signal.trap("USR1") do
      memcached_client.store('lrp1_percent_done', batch_position )
    end
    Signal.trap("TERM") do
      puts "Terminating..."
      stop_processing_at_next_logical_block
    end
  end
  # . . . do some work . . .
while records_left_in_giant_processing_table?
```

---

Overall, though, technically a better architectural strategy is that your long-running process opens a client connection to memcached for another pre-existing service within your network – and writes out the log data to that.

The only thing you will pay for that is the memory for the connection, and vanishingly tiny times for communicating to the memory-based server.

---

You have to think about what it means to write a piece of information so that another process can read it, and what time it takes to do that. Principal and speaking, you either write to a disk for you write to a registered in memory.

A file on disk is akin to a socket.

A register in memory is akin to a report